# Extremely long minor collection times using parallel collector on large heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm running a heavy Java database process with a massive heap (80GB) in Java 10 using the parallel collector. Typically, minor collections take about a few hundred milliseconds which is fine for my use case, but occasionally a minor collection will stall for 40+ seconds! This happens pretty reliably after the process has been restarted and has run for a little while. It doesn't seem to happen again after that first really long stall.

Here are the GC-related JVM arguments:

```
-Xms82329M
-Xmx82329M
-server
-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:NewRatio=1
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256M
-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=100
```

The young generation is purposefully big because there is very little tenured data in the application, so most stuff is short-lived. And I am using the parallel collector because throughput is more important than latency -- both CMS and G1 have not performed as well despite a lot of attempts and tuning.

I'd expect minor collections to have pretty consistent pause times, which seems to be in the 100ms - 1s range for a heap of this size on the hardware I am using. However, I'll see this massive pause once after the application restarts:

```
[755.986s][info][gc,start    ] GC(36) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[756.634s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(36) PSYoungGen: 35519441K->5123933K(36883968K)
[756.634s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(36) ParOldGen: 3724708K->3858421K(42152960K)
[756.634s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(36) Metaspace: 80750K->80750K(83968K)
[756.634s][info][gc          ] GC(36) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 38324M->8771M(77184M) 647.490ms
[756.634s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(36) User=8.19s Sys=0.18s Real=0.65s
[794.053s][info][gc,start    ] GC(37) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[794.563s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(37) PSYoungGen: 36738909K->4366281K(36883968K)
[794.563s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(37) ParOldGen: 3858421K->3963277K(42152960K)
[794.563s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(37) Metaspace: 80798K->80798K(83968K)
[794.563s][info][gc          ] GC(37) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 39645M->8134M(77184M) 509.611ms
[794.563s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(37) User=6.58s Sys=0.00s Real=0.51s
[815.779s][info][gc,start    ] GC(38) Pause Young (GCLocker Initiated GC)
[857.527s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(38) PSYoungGen: 35981257K->4362580K(36883968K)
[857.527s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(38) ParOldGen: 3964998K->4400719K(42152960K)
[857.527s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(38) Metaspace: 80829K->80829K(83968K)
[857.527s][info][gc          ] GC(38) Pause Young (GCLocker Initiated GC) 39010M->8557M(77184M) 41747.938ms
[857.527s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(38) User=490.02s Sys=37.81s Real=41.75s
[891.176s][info][gc,start    ] GC(39) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[892.388s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(39) PSYoungGen: 35977556K->3944941K(36883968K)
[892.388s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(39) ParOldGen: 4400819K->4562823K(42152960K)
[892.388s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(39) Metaspace: 81005K->81005K(83968K)
[892.388s][info][gc          ] GC(39) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 39432M->8308M(77184M) 1211.876ms
[892.388s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(39) User=15.71s Sys=0.00s Real=1.21s
[908.175s][info][gc,start    ] GC(40) Pause Young (GCLocker Initiated GC)
[909.530s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(40) PSYoungGen: 35559917K->4160137K(36883968K)
[909.530s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(40) ParOldGen: 4689915K->4869881K(42152960K)
[909.530s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(40) Metaspace: 81022K->81022K(83968K)
[909.530s][info][gc          ] GC(40) Pause Young (GCLocker Initiated GC) 39306M->8818M(77184M) 1355.504ms
[909.530s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(40) User=17.56s Sys=0.00s Real=1.35s
[939.139s][info][gc,start    ] GC(41) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[939.980s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(41) PSYoungGen: 35775113K->3953721K(36883968K)
[939.980s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(41) ParOldGen: 4869884K->4950314K(42152960K)
[939.980s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(41) Metaspace: 81049K->81049K(83968K)
[939.980s][info][gc          ] GC(41) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 39692M->8695M(77184M) 840.700ms
[939.980s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(41) User=11.30s Sys=0.00s Real=0.84s
[957.230s][info][gc,start    ] GC(42) Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
[957.713s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(42) PSYoungGen: 35568697K->2973501K(36883968K)
[957.713s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(42) ParOldGen: 4950314K->5124031K(42152960K)
[957.713s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(42) Metaspace: 81110K->81110K(83968K)
[957.713s][info][gc          ] GC(42) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 39569M->7907M(77184M) 482.476ms
[957.713s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(42) User=6.07s Sys=0.11s Real=0.49s
[971.819s][info][gc,start    ] GC(43) Pause Young (GCLocker Initiated GC)
[972.230s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(43) PSYoungGen: 34588477K->3388436K(36883968K)
[972.230s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(43) ParOldGen: 5126669K->5177301K(42152960K)
[972.230s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(43) Metaspace: 81144K->81144K(83968K)
[972.230s][info][gc          ] GC(43) Pause Young (GCLocker Initiated GC) 38784M->8364M(77184M) 410.974ms
[972.231s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(43) User=5.29s Sys=0.00s Real=0.40s
```

You'll notice in the middle of the GC logs there is a 40+ second minor collection that has most of the same characteristics as the other minor collections around it (space cleaned up, moved to old generation, etc). So I really can't understand why this reliably happens once after the JVM has been restarted. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about a flight recording after a restart to observe resource allocation? Do you see any anomaly there? By the way, those might be overridden values of some flags related to GC configuration but not all of them, you can PrintFlagsFinal and check if other attributes are assigned compatible with the overridden ones as well.

Comment: Some questions: what java version are you running? 
- You have turned off adaptive size policy? Why? Note that fixing ms == mx does the same thing. Generally speaking adaptive policy is a good thing. 
- Use censum from jclarity (https://www.jclarity.com/censum/) (not affiliated, just a very satisfied customer) to analyze the gc logfile.
- Are you running on a virtual host and are swapping? Swapping during gc on a virtual host incurs a heavy penalty.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm running Java 10. I turned adaptive size policy off because I want to keep the size of the heap regions fixed (50 new, 50 old), don't think that impacts this. It is a virtual host (AWS), but I have swap disabled.